# find Device in C#

Tags: c#

I need my code to respond to the event when my system finds new hardware like USB. How do I go about doing this in C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there are any .Net classes that can help you do this. So you must fall back on calling the Windows API directly.

When a device changes, Windows sends the WM_DEVICECHANGE message. Write your code to respond to this message.

See this [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363480(VS.85).aspx) about WM_DEVICECHANGE. Also, for details on how to write code to respond to it, see [this pdf](http://www.codemiles.com/download/file.php?id=719).

To know about calling Windows API from a C# program, see [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/c__and_api.aspx).